# plyr with nested groups?

Tags: r, plyr

Is there an eloquent way to use `ddply()` to obtain output for not only the most granular groups defined, but also the groups of those sub-groups?

In other words, when one of the classifiers is "any" or "either" or "doesn't matter".  In the simple case of two grouping variables, this can be accomplished by a separate call to `ddply`; however, when there are three or more classifiers that can all be set to "any" this gets messy due having to run `ddply` over and over again for every new combination of "any"+others.

Reproducible example:

```
require(plyr)

## create a data frame with three classification variables
## and two numeric variables:
df1=data.frame(classifier1 = LETTERS[sample(2,200,replace=T)],
classifier2 = letters[sample(3,200,replace=T)],
classifier3 = rep(c("foo","bar"),100),
VAR1 = runif(200,50,250),
VAR2 = rnorm(200,85,20))

## apply an arbitrary function to subsets of df1; that is, all unique
## combinations of the three classifiers.
dlply(df1, .(classifier1,classifier2,classifier3),
      function(df) lm(VAR1 ~ VAR2, data=df))

$A.a.bar

Call:
lm(formula = VAR1 ~ VAR2, data = df)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)         VAR2  
   230.5555      -0.8591  


$A.a.foo

Call:
lm(formula = VAR1 ~ VAR2, data = df)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)         VAR2  
   128.3078       0.3631  

...
```

Now, what if I want to get the same output for a few more groups when any/all classifiers are not included.  For example, if I wanted to include when classifier1="any", I would only include classifier2 and classifier3 in the `dlply` statement, like this:

```
dlply(df1, .(classifier2,classifier3), function(df) lm(VAR1 ~ VAR2, data=df))
```

If I then wanted to get output for when classifier2 and classifier3="any", I would again delete from the `ddply` call and only include classifier1:

```
dlply(df1, .(classifier1), function(df) lm(VAR1 ~ VAR2, data=df))
```

However, this gets unwieldy when I have many more classifiers than three, and each classifier can be taken out (i.e. = "any") -- the number of combinations increases substantially.  Is there an eloquent/fast way to obtain output for all the "groups of groups" of my data?

Comment: You can create each combination separately as strings and pass them directly without the `.()` syntax using something like `expand.grid`.  But I would instead suggest asking a question on stats.exchange regarding your specific problem.  I assume there is a better algorithm for determining relationships than testing all cases.

Comment: Justin -- My question is purely one of organization/computation.  The `lm` function was included as a placeholder for any arbitrary function you or I might want to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach would be to create a list of the combinations and then use `Map` to create a list of the results of each `dlply` call

You can use `combn` in combination with `lapply` and `do.call('c',...)` to create a list of all the combinations of 1,2, ...,n variables

```
xx <- do.call('c',lapply(1:3, function(m) {
           combn(x=names(df1)[1:3],m, simplify = FALSE)}))
```

You can then use this in a call to `Map` (which is a wrapper for `mapply(..., SIMPLIFY = FALSE)`

```
results <- Map(f = function(x){dlply(df1,.var=x, .fun = lm, formula = VAR1 ~ VAR2)},xx)
```

Or you could just pass a function to `combn` -- which will do the same thing

```
results <-  do.call('c',lapply(1:3, function(m) {
  combn(x=names(df1)[1:3],m, simplify = FALSE, 
      function(vv) {dlply(df1,.var=vv, .fun = lm, formula = VAR1~VAR2)})
   }))
```

Comment: This is great -- thank you!  As an aside, I would like to make calls to `results` like this: `results[["A.c.bar"]]`, however the list structure prevents this.  I can accomplish a workaround like this: `for(i in 1:length(results)) results2 = c(r3,results[[i]])` but is there a more efficient way?